# Lambda Select passing extra parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, parameter-passing

I have a Category table where I pass the results into a method :

```
view.Category = ctx.Categories.Select(CategoryMap.IndustryPage).ToList();
```

which works perfect. Now I want to pass in an extra item to the `IndustryPage()` function

```
public static CategoryIndustryView IndustryPage(DAL.Category data, int indID)
```

I tired the following but I know the syntax is way off:

```
view.Category = ctx.Categories.Select(CategoryMap.IndustryPage(this,industryID)).ToList();
```

How can I pass the `indID` into the Select so it is accessible in the `IndustryPage()` function?

**UPDATE / WORKING**

Using @MarcinJuraszek below I was able to get it working with:

```
var catData = ctx.Categories.ToList();
view.Category = catData.Select(x => CategoryMap.IndustryPage(x, industryID)).ToList();
```

I first retrieved the records into catData then did the SELECT .. worked!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) instead of method group:

```
view.Category = ctx.Categories.Select(x => CategoryMap.IndustryPage(x, industryID)).ToList();
```

Comment: Getting an error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'BLL.Views.CategoryIndustryView IndustryPage(DAL.Category, Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @DavidKEgghead That's not connected with the question, is it? Your static method can't be translated into SQL, and that's another problem.

Comment: @DavidKEgghead Yes, it works, because you're fetching entire table into memory and do `Select` as an LINQ to Objects query.

Comment: It depends on what your `IndustryPage` method does.